# Questionamento sobre repetição de preposições, artigos e pronomes

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, pronomes, preposições, artigos-definidos

Olá, estou no ensino médio e desenvolvi interesse por língua portuguesa, porém, uma dúvida surgiu em minha mente: é gramaticalmente correto repetir preposições, artigos e pronomes na mesma frase?

Por exemplo:

*"**Sob** o céu estrelado, caminhávamos **sob** a luz da lua."* (Repetição da preposição "sob")

*"**O** aluno entregou o projeto, e **o** professor se surpreendeu."* (Repetição do artigo "o")

*"**Ele** disse que **ele** mesmo resolveria o problema."* (Repetição do pronome "ele")

Consegui pensar somente nesses exemplos. Isso é considerado aceitável na gramática portuguesa ou um erro que deve ser evitado?

Agradeço antecipadamente pela colaboração e esclarecimento sobre a questão.

Comment: Na gramática, geralmente se prova uma frase gramaticalmente errada (**a**gramatical), e não que é gramatical. É que nem crime: é gramatical até que se prove o contrário. Então, como não conheço nenhuma regra de gramática que proíba essa repetição, está certo. Porém, vejo três efeitos de [estilo](https://www.todamateria.com.br/estilistica/) dessa repetição: 1) repetição é preguiça, enfraquece a palavra e assim enfraquece a frase; 2) dá contraste aos diferentes usos da palavra; 3) normal. Qual destes três? Depende do texto e intenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gramaticalmente falando, nenhum dos exemplos citados é um erro; no entando, algumas palavras podem ser substituídas por sinônimos, com a finalidade de se fazer frases muito mais esteticamente agradáveis:

- artigos são comummente encontrados sendo repetidos em frases; isso não somente é aceitável como quase sempre necessário;
- em seu primeiro exemplo, a repetição da preposição *sob* não configura um erro gramatical mas a segunda preposição pode ser substituída por exemplo por "*caminhávamos debaixo da luz*" ou "*caminhávamos à luz*" se você quiser evitar repetições;
- em seu terceiro exemplo, se houver um contexto onde já se esteja falando "*dele*", a palavra **ele** é completamente opcional: *Disse que o mesmo resolveria o problema*;
- fora isso, muitos substantivos e nomes podem ser trocados por pronomes para se evitar repetição; no exemplo a seguir, a palavra **namorada** é substituída por *ela* na segunda oração: *Ele precisou ir à drogaria com sua namorada, porque ela se esqueceu de trazer sua escova de dentes*.

Comment: Na verdade tenho uma leve dúvida se "ele mesmo" e "o mesmo" têm a mesma conotação.

Answer (score 4):

"Sob o céu estrelado, caminhávamos sob a luz da lua." Está em dois lugares diferentes. Se tirar o segundo, a frase não faz nenhum sentido.

"O aluno entregou o projeto, e o professor se surpreendeu.": professor se surpreendeu não seria boa gramática. São dois seres e usos separados.

"Ele disse que ele mesmo resolveria o problema."
Para fazer sentido, você não pode dizer: Ele disse que mesmo resolveria o problema. ele mesmo é enfático.

Esses usos não são repetições em têrmos de gramática.